# у меня всё сохраняется и выводится, но css не применяется. почему и как эту проблему решить?

Tags: button

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="fuf()">кликЕР</button>
    <div class="body"></div>
    <script src="code.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
.gfd {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(15, 136, 26, 0.719);
}
```

js

```
let ghj = document.querySelector('.body');
function fuf() {
  ghj.innerHTML += '<main class="gfd">mv</main>';
  localStorage.setItem('key', document.querySelector('.body').innerHTML);
}
ghj.innerHTML += localStorage.getItem('key');
```

Comment: конкретно что именно у вас не работает - по приведённому вопросу тяжело понять

Comment: А где вы подключаете css к документу?

Comment: @Zhihar, легко.

Comment: как-то я тупанул и в правду css не подключил

Answer (score 1):

Вы не подключили файл
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="myfile.css">` Подключите это в теге `<head></head>`

Answer (score 0):

А с какой стати ему применяться, если он даже на страницу не подключен?

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/671910)

Comment: @VanyambaElectronics, почему не является?